# Mostrar un arreglo en React

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Estoy tratando de recorrer un arreglo con map y mostrarlo en la vista de React, pero este no me aparece.

```js
import React from 'react'

const Formulario = () => {

const arreglo= [1,2,3,4,5];

    return (
        <>
        <h2>listas</h2>

        {
           arreglo.map((item) =>{
               <h3>{item}</h3>
           })
        }
        </>
    )
}
export default Formulario
```

En cambio, si se me muestra por consola, al colocar el map sobre el return.

```js
arreglo.map((item) =>{
    console.log(item);
})
```

El conjunto del código en general esta bien, porque me muestra otros elementos, pero el bloque del map no me muestra nada. Tampoco me funciona utilizando una función normal dentro del map . Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la función tiene llaves se debe usar `return`

```
arreglo.map((item) => {
      return  <h3>{item}</h3>
 })
```

Si no tiene llaves no hay que poner return:

```
arreglo.map((item) => <h3>{item}</h3>)
```

Answer (score 0):

adicionalmente, si necesitas asignar a otro array el resultado por que usualmente es el array modificado.

```
    const nuevoArreglo = arreglo.map((item) => {
     // mas instrucciones posibles
     return  <h3>{item}</h3>
     })
```